# Using awk to display text instead of opening a file

Tags: awk

I have a list of file names - simulated by

```
f="HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A.dedup.sorted.bam  HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_B.dedup.sorted.bam"
```

I would like my operation to select the text `"HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A.dedup.sorted.bam"` and process this to `"HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A"`

I am trying

```
echo $f | awk '/_A/ { echo }' | sed 's/.dedup.sorted.bam//g'
```

but am getting stuck in the very beginning

```
awk '/_A/ { echo }' $f
```

gives me the error

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A.dedup.sorted.bam' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

I don't want it to open any file. I would just like it to parse the list to produce a truncated string.

Comment: Where is the `f` coming from? Why are you populating the filename expansion results to a variable?

Comment: the script is ~200 lines long, so i thought it would communicate my problem concisely. I am turning it into a variable so i can output it in a .csv that will be used later by another program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1st Solution:*** In `awk` it doesn't work like BASH we have a separate `print`function for it `echo` wouldn't work in it. You could try following(this will remove everything from `.` to till last of line for all parts of your passed variable.

```
echo "$f" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/\..*/,"",$i);print $i}}'
HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A
HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_B
```

---

---

***2nd solution In case you want to look for specific string and remove some parts from it then try following:***

```
echo "$f"  | awk 'match($0,/HDAC3[^ ]*/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/\..*/,"",val);print val}'
HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A
```

OR(a non-one liner form of solution):

```
f="HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A.dedup.sorted.bam  HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_B.dedup.sorted.bam"
echo "$f"  | 
awk '
   match($0,/HDAC3[^ ]*/){
      val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
      sub(/\..*/,"",val)
      print val
   }
'
```

***3rd Solution:*** In case anyone wants to look for exact string then try following.

```
echo "$f"  | awk 'match($0,/HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D[0-9]+_A/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

---

---

***4th Solution:*** In case there could multiple occurrences of `_A` in lines of different fields then try following.

Assuming that your variable `f` is having following values.

```
echo "$f"
HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A.dedup.sorted.bam  HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_B.dedup.sorted.bam  HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D01_A.dedup.sorted.bam
```

***Now when we run the new code:***

```
echo "$f" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D[0-9]+_A/){print $i}}}' 
HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A.dedup.sorted.bam
HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D01_A.dedup.sorted.bam
```

---

---

***Problems found in OP's attempt:***

- `awk` don't have `echo` function in it, it has `print instead.
- `awk` when you are trying to pass like `awk......$f` it means you are passing an Input_file to it which is NOT the case here so you shouldn't do it.
- If it is a text which you want to pass to `awk` and process then try either `echo "text here...." | awk code here.` OR `awk ..... <<<"$var"` for an example.

Comment: Thanks! It completely obviated sed.

How do I only get  "HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A" (excluding  HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_B)?

Comment: @Adi, ok sure, please try my 2nd solution in that case and let me know?

Comment: @Adi, this could be down with single `awk` so I have added that solution in my post, we need not to use multiple tools for this requirement IMHO.

Comment: @Adi, please check my post I have added 4 solutions now, let me know if 3rd or 4th helps you? If not then mention your question more clearly, let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `echo` exists in awk, you'll want `print` instead, and print only the first field, `$1`:

```
$ f="HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A.dedup.sorted.bam  HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_B.dedup.sorted.bam"
$ echo $f | awk '/_A/ { print $1 }' | sed 's/.dedup.sorted.bam//g'
HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A
```

The error about opening files is because you passed `$f` to `awk` on the command line, rather than piping the variable's contents into `awk`. Command line arguments to `awk` are taken to be file names. You could put your actual filename there, but not this `$f` variable (which I assume contains some example content of the input file, rather than names of input files).

Comment: IMHO, we need to do use `awk` and `sed` for these, we could do it  in single `awk` or `sed`(again this would be for processing and efficiency purposes only).

Comment: Thanks, that was really easy to follow. I really appreciate it

Comment: I believe that your command is finding the string with _A by using $1, is there a way to find it using "_A", in case its positioning within the list is not constant?

Comment: @Adi, If you see my 3rd solution it looks for string `HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D[0-9]+_A` and then prints it, let me know if this helps you? NOTE: Here it is assuming that you need text like `HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D`digits`_A`.

Comment: @Adi, or do let us know if you want to find `_A` in each field of line? Like `HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D01_A` and `HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D02_A` etc etc?

Comment: I really appreciate the time you have spent on this. 

The names keep changing, the only constants are that there will be a *_A.dedup.sorted.bam and a *_B.dedup.sorted.bam. (The A and the B indicate replicates). I was hoping to filter out the *_A.dedup.sorted.bam from the pair and remove the .dedup.sorted.bam yielding *_A

Comment: @Adi, please check my 4th solution which will do that what you have asked now. Also in case you only need to put regex `$i~/.*_A/` in check condition of 4th solution and it should do the trick. Request you to please reoly on my solution's comments as I am not getting pop up here.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do (using GNU awk for multi-char RS)?

```
$ echo "$f" | awk -v RS='\\s+' 'sub(/_A\.dedup\.sorted\.bam$/,"_A")'
HDAC3_CTRL_Diff-D0_A
```